# What is the difference between Random Controller and Random order controller?

Tags: jmeter, controllers

Please, anyone of you, clear my doubt with a simple example for my above question?

Answer (score 10):

Random Order Controller plays all Samplers that are its children but in a random order

Random Controller plays only one of its children samples picking it randomly

Reference documentation is here:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Random_Controller
- https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Random_Order_Controller

Answer (score 1):

**Random Controller**: It will pick one sampler/request at random from all those added under it and executes it. Like: if you have 10 HTTP requests samplers under a random controller then this controller will execute only 1 of them, randomly.

**Random order controller**: It will pick all samplers placed under it, but in a random order. Like: If you have 10 HTTP request samplers under a random order controller then this controller will execute ALL of them, but in a random order each time.